# using cursor inside cursor to loop through table values in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a problem where I am trying to update a value of a table using another table through cursor.

```
create table A (product varchar2, loc varchar2, qty1 number s_date date);
insert into table A values('123','1',40,sysdate+2);
insert into table A values('123','1',50,sysdate+4);
insert into table A values('124','1',0,sysdate+2);
insert into table A values('124','1',0,sysdate+2);

create table B (p1 varchar2, p2 varchar2,loc2 varchar2, qty2 number, a_date date);
insert into table B values('123','124','1',30,sysdate+1);
insert into table B values('123','124','1',20,sysdate+2);
insert into table B values('123','124','1',50,sysdate+3);
```

Now the requirement is first sort A and B in ascending order of dates
then

```
for p1 = product and loc2 = loc
    for p2 = product and loc2=loc
   if qty1>=qty2 and qty1>0 then
      qty1 = qty1-qty2 where product = p1
   else 
     move to next row of table A
       next.qty1 = qty1-(qty2-previous.qty1)
```

then we move on to next row of Table B and check if current qty1 from table A >0 and repeat the same process.I am using oracle 18c.

I am trying to acheive this by using 2 cursors but not really getting it. Is there any other way to implement this? can someone please help?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the expected output for your sample data.

Comment: Also, your pseudo-code does not make sense as when you do not have any rows in `A` where both `p1 = product` and `p2 = product` for the same `B` row so the assumption is that you have two different rows of `A` to make the `FOR` loops work and then in the third row it will be unclear which `A.qty1` you are referring to. A worked example explaining in plain English (not pseudo-code) with the expected output and reasoning would help to clarify your question.

Comment: Here, we are taking 2 values from B and matching them with 2 rows of A...for example , here first we check p1 = product sop 123 = 123 and p2 = product for same row so 124 = 124 then, we take qty from that row which is 30. then we subtract it from qty in A which is 40 so we get diff as 10. Now , we take next row of B..again match and we get qty as 20 so since 20>10(diff remaining) we subtract 10 from first row of A and 10 from next row so result will be 40 in row 2 of table A. Final out put will be: for table A       qty: 0 for row 1 , 40 for row 2

Comment: Please don't post clarification in comments; [edit] your question and format it neatly so that it is easy to read and understand.

Comment: @HeatherDante I edited my code to match your description of the wanted output can u check if it is what you are looking for?

Comment: @HeatherDante You also said in your question: "requirement is first sort A and B in ascending order of dates" but here in your comment where you explain your desired algorithm your order of going thro rows of table A is default (rows are ordered by time they were inserted), second row `A.qty1 ordered by s_date asc` should be 0 not 50, 50 is the forth row.

Comment: @ToniAntunović Thanks for the suggestion! I tweaked it a bit and it works. I decided to use a cursor to get ordered rows and that works too. I will play around a bit with this and see if I can apply this on other conditions too. thanks a lot!

Comment: @ToniAntunović you are correct. It was my mistake. We need to go through data in order of s_date, product,loc. What is needed is more complicated but in my solution , I am using 2 cursors since we can get ordered data and looping is needed here. Though I needed a lot of IF statements,  it is working for now. I was thinking of using collection and data partition but rows are in millions so its taking too much time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code that stores whole a and b table into a collection and makes your calculations with `A.qty1` if the conditions are satisfied. I made at the end of the code a `dbms_output.put_line` of the A table collection because I m not sure I understood right your "pseudo code" where u describe conditions and calculation.  Look up the server output and if the calculation done on A table collection are right it is easy to update a table with collection. Also note that  this is not a very fast solution we are loading whole two tables into a collection (if your table A or B has million rows this will be executing forever) so try to use where in the `select into` clause to load only the rows u need for that update.

Sample data:

```
create table A (product varchar2(10), loc varchar2(10), qty1 number, s_date date);
insert into A values('123','1',40,sysdate+2);
insert into  A values('123','1',50,sysdate+4);

create table B (p1 varchar2(10), p2 varchar2(10),loc2 varchar2(10), qty2 

insert into  B values('123','124','1',30,sysdate+1);
insert into  B values('123','124','1',20,sysdate+2);
```

Pl/SQL code:

```
set SERVEROUTPUT ON;
declare
    type t_A_collection is table of a%rowtype index by pls_integer;
    v_A_collection t_A_collection;
    
    type t_B_collection is table of b%rowtype index by pls_integer;
    v_B_collection t_B_collection;
    
    v_previous_qty1 a.qty1%type;
begin
    select * bulk collect into v_A_collection from a order by s_date asc;
    select * bulk collect into v_B_collection from b order by a_date asc;
    
    for i in v_B_collection.first..v_B_collection.last loop
        --for j in v_A_collection.first..v_A_collection.last loop
      
            if v_A_collection.exists(i-1) then
                if v_B_collection(i).qty2>v_A_collection(i-1).qty1 then
                   v_A_collection(i).qty1:=v_A_collection(i).qty1-(v_B_collection(i).qty2-v_A_collection(i-1).qty1);
                    v_A_collection(i-1).qty1:=0;
                end if;
            else
                if v_B_collection(i).p1=v_A_collection(i).product
                and  v_B_collection(i).loc2=v_A_collection(i).loc then
                    v_A_collection(i).qty1:= abs(v_A_collection(i).qty1-v_B_collection(i).qty2);
                elsif v_B_collection(i).p2=v_A_collection(i).product then
                    v_A_collection(i).qty1:= abs(v_A_collection(i).qty1-v_B_collection(i).qty2);
                end if;
            end if;       
    end loop;
    for i in v_A_collection.first..v_A_collection.last loop
        dbms_output.put_line(v_A_collection(i).product||' '||v_A_collection(i).loc||' '||v_A_collection(i).qty1||' '||v_A_collection(i).s_date);
    end loop;
end;
```

Server output of collection for table A:

```
PRODUCT|LOC |QTY1 |S_DATE
-----------------------------
123     1    0     30.04.2022
123     1    40    02.05.2022
```